# In Erlang, how can I independently capture stdout and stderr of a subprocess?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the stdout and stderr from a system subprocess in Erlang.  (Not to be confused with an Erlang process.)  The gotcha is I'm trying to pull the output of the streams independently.

open_port/2 seems to get me most of the way there, however it doesn't seem to provide a way to differentiate between the two streams.  There is the stderr_to_stdout option, but that's not what I want; I want to get data from both data streams but be able to distinguish the two streams.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

**Update:** I'm ideally looking for a solution that will work on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try [erlexec](https://github.com/saleyn/erlexec). As [its documentation](http://saleyn.github.io/erlexec/) explains, it allows separate control over stdout and stderr, and in general it's much more flexible than `open_port/2` for managing OS processes from Erlang.

Comment: Hmm...  This looks promising.  One part I didn't mention in my question is I'm looking for a solution that works on both Windows and Linux; erlexec does not appear to "support" Windows.  I'll still try it and see if it works despite being unsupported.

Comment: ...and the answer is "no".  Support would need to be added.  Which _may_ end up being the answer; hoping there's an easier alternative though...

Comment: Based on lack of response from others, going to consider a Windows-compatible solution as being a possible gap.  Putting Windows aside, erlexec does seem like the right fit in general, thus I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Also, having studied a little more Erlang now, my likely solution is: create a small program in another language (e.g. Python) and have it communicate via open_port/2 using spawn_executable plus the use_stdio option.  I can capture what I need via the in-between module, encode it in JSON, and then suck that into Erlang via the in-between module's stdout.

Downside is that I'm relying on an "external" program in between Erlang and the subprocess I want to capture output from...  But this isn't particularly hard, and lets me be lazy and not port erlexec to Windows.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Path = filename:join(["./priv", "log", "log_file_name"]),
{ok, F} = file:open(Path, [write]),
group_leader(F, self()),
erlang:display("Anything this process outputs now gets redirected").
```

Comment: Interesting and good knowledge for me to know...  The question though was regarding capturing stdout/stderr of external processes, not Erlang processes.

Comment: I think you can consider to edit the question to say "from a system process using Erlang" vs "from a subprocess in Erlang" as that can confuse future Googlies.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's fair.